# Iphone 3d rotation for 2 buttons

Tags: iphone

In my IPhone application, I have two buttons with background image set.

At any time one button is active an the other one is inactive.

I want to display the two buttons in 3d style such that the active image is in front and the other on is at the back but visible.

When the user clicks the inactive button, it should come to the front and the the other one should go back, with both the buttons rotating like 3d effect.

Can anyone suggest an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Start by studying the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), with particular interest in the example code given for an animated menu.